# Grails and bitbucket

Tags: git, grails, bitbucket

I have a grails project and when I commit it and push to the bitbucket remote, in bitbucket I noticed, that taglib, utils, services folders are not pushed. what is the problem? there are no files in this folders. but earlier there's not such problem even if this folders are empty.

P.S. pardon for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Bitbucket 'problem', but a Git problem/feature.  Using standard Git, you cannot add empty directories.

see:https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F